# Kubernetes Worker Node in Status NotReady after introducing a proxy in between worker node and control plane

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I have setup a  `kubernetes` cluster with `kubeamd`; One control-plane and a worker node.

Everything worked fine. Then 
I setup a Squid proxy on the worker node and in the `kubelet` config I have set `http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128` essentially asking `kubelet` to use the proxy to communicate to the control-plane.

I see, using tcpdump, network packets landing on the control plane from worker node, and I am able to issue the following command from worker as well;

```
kubectl get no --server=https://10.128.0.63:6443
NAME        STATUS     ROLES    AGE    VERSION
k8-cp       Ready      master   6d6h   v1.17.0
k8-worker   NotReady   <none>   6d6h   v1.17.2
```

but the worker status always remains NotReady.
What might I be doing wrong?

I am using Flannel here for networking.

P.S. I have exported `http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128` as an env variable as well before issuing

```
kubectl get no --server=https://10.128.0.63:6443
```

from the worker node.

If it matters here is the node status;

```
kubectl  describe no k8-worker
Name:               k8-worker
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=k8-worker
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
Annotations:        flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-data: {"VtepMAC":"fe:04:d6:53:ef:cc"}
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/backend-type: vxlan
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/kube-subnet-manager: true
                    flannel.alpha.coreos.com/public-ip: 10.128.0.71
                    kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket: /var/run/dockershim.sock
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Wed, 29 Jan 2020 08:08:33 +0000
Taints:             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute
                    node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoSchedule
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  k8-worker
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Thu, 30 Jan 2020 11:51:24 +0000
Conditions:
  Type             Status    LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason              Message
  ----             ------    -----------------                 ------------------                ------              -------
  MemoryPressure   Unknown   Thu, 30 Jan 2020 11:48:25 +0000   Thu, 30 Jan 2020 11:52:08 +0000   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  DiskPressure     Unknown   Thu, 30 Jan 2020 11:48:25 +0000   Thu, 30 Jan 2020 11:52:08 +0000   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  PIDPressure      Unknown   Thu, 30 Jan 2020 11:48:25 +0000   Thu, 30 Jan 2020 11:52:08 +0000   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  Ready            Unknown   Thu, 30 Jan 2020 11:48:25 +0000   Thu, 30 Jan 2020 11:52:08 +0000   NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  10.128.0.71
  Hostname:    k8-worker
Capacity:
  cpu:                2
  ephemeral-storage:  104844988Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             7493036Ki
  pods:               110
Allocatable:
  cpu:                2
  ephemeral-storage:  96625140781
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             7390636Ki
  pods:               110
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 3221f625fa75d20f08bceb4cacf74e20
  System UUID:                6DD87A9F-7F72-5326-5B84-1B3CBC4D9DBE
  Boot ID:                    7412bb51-869f-40de-8b37-dcbad6bf84b4
  Kernel Version:             3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64
  OS Image:                   CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  docker://1.13.1
  Kubelet Version:            v1.17.2
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.17.2
PodCIDR:                      10.244.1.0/24
PodCIDRs:                     10.244.1.0/24
Non-terminated Pods:          (3 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                           CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                   ----                           ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  default                     nginx-86c57db685-fvh28         0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         6d20h
  kube-system                 kube-flannel-ds-amd64-b8vbr    100m (5%)     100m (5%)   50Mi (0%)        50Mi (0%)      6d23h
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-rsr7l               0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         6d23h
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests   Limits
  --------           --------   ------
  cpu                100m (5%)  100m (5%)
  memory             50Mi (0%)  50Mi (0%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)     0 (0%)
Events:              <none>
```

Link to kubelet logs on worker:

https://pastebin.com/E90FNEXR

Comment: can you provide kubelet logs from the worker

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I have added the link `https://pastebin.com/E90FNEXR`

Comment: why do you need Kubelet to communicate thru Squid? Did you made any configuration to the Kube-api master? because you may need to set the http_proxy in both in order to achieve two-way communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kube-controller-manager/node-controller is responsible for monitoring the health of the nodes monitoring the endpoint **"/healthz"** exposed by kubelet.

So far you have configured a one way communication over proxy (from Node to Master).

You need to do it for other components, especially Kube-controller-manager.
This way you enable two way communication over HTTP Proxy.

> This is achievable by specifying **HTTP_PROXY** on **KUBEADM INIT:**
>
> `$ sudo http_proxy=192.168.1.20:3128 kubeadm init`

Learn more here:  [Kubadm Issue 182](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/182)

- It creates a one-time variable which is read-in by kubeadm, and then re-created inside all components of control plane also as Env Variable.

You will see some output like this:

```
kubeadm@lab-1:~$ sudo http_proxy=192.168.1.20:3128 kubeadm init 
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.17.0
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
        [WARNING HTTPProxy]: Connection to "https://10.156.0.6" uses proxy "http://192.168.1.20:3128". If that is not intended, adjust your proxy settings
        [WARNING HTTPProxyCIDR]: connection to "10.96.0.0/12" uses proxy "http://192.168.1.20:3128". This may lead to malfunctional cluster setup. Make sure that Pod and Services IP ranges specified correctly as exceptions in proxy configuration
```

- Optionally you can do this manually through Env Variable, like you did for kubelet by adjusting kube-controller-manager's pod spec.

Learn more here: [Kubeadm Issue 324](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/324).